# not all code paths return a value ' '

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple shotgun game where the user vs the CPU and the both pick shot, shield or reload but In my GetOptionFromUser I keep getting the error 'ShotgunGame.Program.GetOptionFromUser()': not all code paths return a value

Any Guidance would be appreciated Here is my methods

```
enum ShotgunOption
{
    Shoot = 1,
    Reload = 2,
    Shield = 3,
}

static void DisplayMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please pick an item:");
    Console.WriteLine("S - Shoot");
    Console.WriteLine("P - Shield");
    Console.WriteLine("R - Reload");         
    //Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
}


static ShotgunOption GetOptionFromUser()
{
    char menuItem;
    DisplayMenu();
    menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

    if (menuItem == 'S')
    {
        return ShotgunOption.Shoot;
    }
    else if (menuItem == 'P')
    {
        return ShotgunOption.Shield;
    }
    else if (menuItem == 'R')
    {
        return ShotgunOption.Reload;
    }

    while (menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'R')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error - Invalid menu item");
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
}

static void DisplayResults(ShotgunOption UserOption,ShotgunOption CPUOption, int UserScore, int UserBullets, int CPUBullets)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Giving up?");
    Console.WriteLine("You Chose {0}, The Computer Chose{1} Your Score is {3} . You had {4} Bullet(s). The CPU had {5} bullets(s).", UserOption, CPUOption, UserScore, UserBullets, CPUBullets);
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You need a return after the while statement in the GetOptionFromUser function. Something like return ShotgunOption.None;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a series of `if` `else if`'s that return things. But you then have

```
while (menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'P' &&
        menuItem != 'R')
...
```

with no return statements. You need a return at the end of your method, as well as in your `if`'s.

What you are trying to do, and what your code does, are a little apart. Something like this will serve you better:

```
static ShotgunOption GetOptionFromUser()
{
    char menuItem = null;
    DisplayMenu();
    var menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

    while (menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'P' && menuItem != 'R')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error - Invalid menu item");
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    if (menuItem == 'S')
    {
        return ShotgunOption.Shoot;
    }
    else if (menuItem == 'P')
    {
        return ShotgunOption.Shield;
    }
    return ShotgunOption.Reload;
}
```

This way, the code loops until it has a valid value and then handles which item to return after it leaves the loop, ensuring something is returned by every path through the code.

Answer (score 4):

In your `GetOptionFromUser` function, after the `if/else if/else if` structure, there are no return statements. Once the program exits that structure and enters the `while` loop, there is no way for it to return from the function, which is invalid behavior.